# How to get all events from all rooms (or selected users) in microsoft graph?

Tags: azure, outlook, azure-ad-graph-api

I would like to get events from selected rooms in microsoft graph (rooms are users too).
As I understand the API from graph:
I need to call

> GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/events/

for each user/room to get all events for rooms or I need to create groups and call:

> GET /groups/{id}/events/

Is there a possibility to pass more than 1 Id to get different results ?
Or any other way to get events from provided range of users (rooms)?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

There is no such REST can return the events of multiple users directly. However we can use the batch request to send the multiple request in a single request.

Here is a sample that retrieve events from two users:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$batch

Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
authorization: bearer {access_token} 

{
  "requests": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "method": "GET",
      "url": "/users/user1@{tenantName}.onmicrosoft.com/events"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "method": "GET",
      "url": "/users/user1@{tenantName}.onmicrosoft.com/events"
    }
  ]
}
```

To read events from multiple users, **Read calendars in all mailboxes** is required. You can use the client credential flow to acquire the token for this permission. More detail about batch request please refer link below:

[Combine multiple requests in one HTTP call using JSON batching (preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/json-batching)